# FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres" While connecting to postgres

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I tried to create server it it says:

Unable to connect to server:

FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

https://prnt.sc/ric1vl

Comment: Apparently you provided the wrong password for the database user `postgres`

Answer (score 0):

What operating system are you using? maybe you need to change the password of the postgres user. In my case I use Debian GNU Linux, to change the password of the postgres user, I do it in the following way:

```
root@alpha:~$ passwd postgres
```

and then I enter a new password for the user.

Could you also verify that the `postgres` user has permission to connect to the server? To do this, you can check the `pg_hba.config` file in the PostgreSQL. installation directory.

```
root@alpha:~$ nano /etc/postgresql/11/main/pg_hba.conf
```

By default PostgreSQL, only allows connections from local addresses (localhost)

Comment: The error message indicates the password for the **database** user is wrong, not for the operating system user.

Comment: PostgreSQL, after installing, automatically creates a user named ```postgres``` in the operating system, this user's password, you can change it, as if it were a normal user .. (in fact it is) in your case, you are trying to connect to the ```postgresql server``` with this user ... so I suggest you check if the password you are actually using to connect is really the password that user has on the server.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure to have your local postgres server running
2. Hit pgadmin tool connect to server and to create database
3. Right-click on the server button to your left, select create then server, insert name of the server, make sure it is as descriptive as possible, that way you can find your way back to if you remember
4. Move to connection tab; host name is the server where the SQL database is running, most likely you will be starting with your machine as database(db), insert localhost or 127.0.0.1.

   leave default port as it is '5432'
   maintenance db leave as 'postgres'
   username  leave as default 'postgres'
   password : same as you registered with during installation

To your left, you should see the database under 'server', you should see the postgres default created underlink databases.

Right click on the databases button and select create, then database, insert your descriptive database name, click save.

Click on your new database, roll down, highlight Schema, go to Tools, select Query Tool...

You can go ahead to create or import tables as you deem fit.

EMPHASIS SHOULD BE ON THE PASSWORD, IT MUST BE SAME AS USED DURING INSTALLATION